# A function to find the sum of prime factors of an integer number

Tags: c, function, prime-factoring

I am not able to meet all the conditions of prime factors of a number so that I find the correct sum.

```
    int sumPrime(number){


         int counter;
         int sum=0;
         for(counter=2;counter<=(number/2);counter++){
           if(number%counter==0){
              sum=counter;
              counter++;
              sum+=counter;


              }
           return sum;  

          }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Try mentioning some input and corresponding output.

Comment: First write a function to find prime factors.

Comment: Well, the input will be any positive integer number. The output will be its prime factors sum.

Comment: Well if the input is 12= 4*3=2*2*3 the output should be 2+2+3=7

Comment: Ok, so one problem is that you only check each factor once, i.e. the loop only checks to see if 2 divides into 12, not how many times 2 divides into 12.

Comment: Going up to number/2 in the for loop is inefficient, see my answer for the more efficient sqrt(number).

Answer (score 2):

I think the code is self explanatory. It works for `number >= 2`.

```
int sumPrime(int number){
     int factor = 2;
     int sum=0;

    while(1 != number){ //Repeat the loop till number becomes 1.
       if(number%factor==0){ //Check if factor divides the number.
          number /= factor; //If yes, update the number.
          sum+=factor; //Add factor to sum.
          printf("Factor [%d]\n", factor);
          continue;
        }
        factor++; //If the current number is not a factor, check the next number.
    }
    printf("Sum [%d]\n", sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Output for 12:

```
Factor [2]                                                                                                                                      
Factor [2]                                                                                                                                      
Factor [3]                                                                                                                                      
Sum [7]
```

Comment: In the `sumPrime(int number)`, add in the while-loop `if (factor>2) factor++;` at the end (before the `factor++`) to search prime number only with odd integers (half number of factors tries).

Comment: @J.Piquard: Yes. You are right. Since That optimization can be done.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){


    printf("sum is%i",sumCount(12));
    return 0;
}
int sumCount(int number){
int count,sum=0;
for(count=2;count<number;count++){
    if(isPrime(count)==1){
        printf("%i \n",count);
        sum+=count;
    }
}
return sum;
}
int isPrime(int number){
    int i;
    for (i=2;i<=number/2 ;i++){
        if(number%i==0){
        return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: In the `isPrime(int number)`, add in the for-loop `if (i>2) i++;` at the end to search prime number only with odd integers.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient algorithm to find the prime factors

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int sumPrime(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    printf ("%6d: ", n);

    // find all powers of 2
    while (n%2 == 0) {
        printf("%d+", 2);
        n /= 2;
        sum += 2;
    }

    // checking for factors up to sqrt(n) is sufficient
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        // find all powers of i
        while (n%i == 0) {
            printf("%d+", i);
            n /= i;
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    // n is prime at this point
    if (n > 2) {
        printf ("%d", n);
        sum += n;
    }

    printf (" = %d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

void main() {
    sumPrime(226);
    sumPrime(39);
    sumPrime(775);
}
```

**Output:**

```
   226: 2+113 = 115
    39: 3+13 = 16
   775: 5+5+31 = 41
```

Comment: Rather than `i <= sqrt(n)` consider `i <= n/i` to avoid FP issues and `int/double` precision differences.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let n = 22;
let sum = 0;

function sumOfPrimeFactors(n) {
  // Write your code here
  if(n === 2){
    return true;
  }
  if(n < 2 || isNaN(n) || (n%2===0)){
    return false;
  }
  for(let i = 3; i < n; i++){
    if(n%i === 0){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

for(let i = 0; i <= n; i++){
  if(sumOfPrimeFactors(i) === true){
    if(n % i === 0){
      sum += i;
    }
  }
}
console.log(`The sum of the prime factors in 91 is: ${sum}`)
```